# Inheritance system for folders (symlinks?)

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-management, symbolic-link, hardlink

Okay, here's the scenario.

I have a base folder "Base" that has a blank, multipurpose template. However, this template is 12 gigabytes. I want to be able to have an inheritance system where linked folders have their own content, but use their parent folder's content when they can't find it. Say I have 3 different projects "A", "B", and "C". I want A, B, and C to all point to Base. However, I want to be able to overwrite certain files in A, without modifying anything in Base, B, or C. And maybe I want to add a few files in B without them showing up in Base, A, or C. That way, I can still have all the functionality of Base, but with only the file changes taking up space and the rest only needing to exist once (in Base).

Bottom line, I want a folder inheritance system (or a 1 way symlink) for explorer.exe on Windows 8. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you should start running a less rigid OS for your dev environment. Forgive my non-answer response.

Answer (score 0):

You can create symlinks on Windows using the `mklink` command.

Use `mklink -H` to create a hard link which will give your folder structure the impression that the linked file actually does reside at the location of the link.

Creating the rest of the inheritance structure would probably be up to you.

Comment: That would work, except that when I edit the file that I just linked in A, the file in Base also changes.

Comment: You could set the file attributes to read-only so that whenever you wanted to make a change, you had to create a new file in folder A that you resolve your links to locally rather than now pointing towards the Base folder. Out of interest, what's the problem domain you're working in?

Comment: Personal. Honestly I just want a profile system for my Skyrim mods.